# Qt move label with mouse

Tags: qt, makefile, installation, qmake, qt4.7

So here's the thing: I downloaded the Qt 4.7 tar and I'm installing on Ubuntu 16. I unzip the downloaded folder and installed all libs that were preventing me to run the ./configure
After I could run the configure, the make runs but get an error at some point. Here's what I get when I run 'make configure' or 'make':

`root@ubuntu:/home/gimenes/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.0# make configure
/home/gimenes/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.0/bin/qmake -spec mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -o Makefile projects.pro
make: /home/gimenes/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.0/bin/qmake: Command not found
Makefile:1063: recipe for target 'Makefile' failed
make: *** [Makefile] Error 127
root@ubuntu:/home/gimenes/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.0# make
/home/gimenes/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.0/bin/qmake -spec mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -o Makefile projects.pro
make: /home/gimenes/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.0/bin/qmake: Command not found
Makefile:1063: recipe for target 'Makefile' failed
make: *** [Makefile] Error 127`

I really appreciate the help, Ty :D

Comment: Why such an old and outdated version ? Can't you at least use the distribution provided Qt which should be 4.8.7 ?

Comment: No path to qmake. And no connection between the title of this post and the question. Plus no single question mark to define the question.